# Blocking call in Swing event listener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, synchronization

In my swing application I have implemented a listener for key up. For each call to the listener, a connection is made to a database on connected over internet. In my development environment I'm using the server on the same machine, so not experiencing any latency. In real scenario with this setup, what will be the implications when one key up is called before the earlier one has completed its fetching ? Will it make my application unresponsive or the call to listener method is queued on a separate thread ?

P.S: New to swing development.

Comment: Why down vote ?? Mention the reason you down vote so that I can improve the question.

Comment: Are you trying to implement some kind of auto-complete?

Comment: @peeskillet : Yes. Also I have used a the same method for sending data to the server when focus is lost.

Comment: It is a large dataset? Is it possible to load the data to the combo box (or whatever component) initially?

Comment: @peeskillet: Yes. It is a very large data set in the deployment situation.

Comment: It's an interesting issue I've never put much research into. Have you done research for the most efficient way to implement this, not just in Swing, but any technology? I'm sure there's a bunch of questions/answers/topics out there where this is discussed. The approach would seem the same for a web app or a desktop app

Comment: Almost all the time, I want the UI to be responsive, so I use a separate thread and en-queue the request to that thread. Now, I want to block the application to wait until the request is finished. So, using an individual thread is ruled out.

Comment: I tried to sleep the eventlistener thread and the application became unresponsive, which is what I wanted exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Mmmm ... depends. If internally every time you do a query when you press a key you have something like this:

worker = new WorkerSQL (query); 
worker.execute ();

Pulsed consultation provided key will be made as part of the "worker" a new connection is made ​​to the database but only a request will be made. 
If you have only one connection and worker inside there's a Wait () until you have a connection available. A query will be made after another. 
Look for "pool of connections" to make several queries at once.

sorry for my English.

Comment: I have difficulties in understanding in what you have said. +1 for mentioning 'pool of connections'.